# Bash script to return domains instead of URL's

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have this bash script that i wrote to analyse the html of any given web page. What its actually supposed to do is to return the domains on that page. Currently its returning the number of URL's on that web page.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter a url eg www.bbc.com:"
read url
content=$(wget "$url" -q -O -)
echo "Enter file name to store URL output"
read file
echo $content > $file
echo "Enter file name to store filtered links:"
read links
found=$(cat $file | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d '"' -f2 | sort | uniq | awk   '/http/' > $links)
output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)
cat out
```

How can i get it to return the domains instead of the URL's. From my programming knowledge I know its supposed to do parsing from the right but i am a newbie at bash scripting. Can someone please help me. This is as far as I have gone.

Comment: You lose line breaks and whitespace with an unquoted `echo`. But actually, I would obtain the URL and the filename, then `wget -O "$filename" "$url"`

Answer (score 2):

I know there's a better way to do this in awk but you can do this with sed, by appending this after your `awk '/http/'`:

```
| sed -e 's;https\?://;;' | sed -e 's;/.*$;;'
```

Then you want to move your sort and uniq to the end of that.

So that the whole line will look like:

```
found=$(cat $file | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d '"' -f2 | awk   '/http/' | sed -e 's;https\?://;;' | sed -e 's;/.*$;;' | sort | uniq -c > out)
```

You can get rid of this line:

```
output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)
```

Comment: Yes this is close but when i run it it doesnt return how many occurences each domain appears on the webpage that is queried like it was doing with the URL's. Its output is like this                                   advertising.bbcworldwide.com
news.bbc.co.uk
newsvote.bbc.co.uk
purl.org
static.bbci.co.uk
www.bbcamerica.com
www.bbc.com
www.bbc.co.uk
www.browserchoice.eu
www.omniture.com

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2:**
Please note, that you might want to adapt the search patterns in the `sed` expressions to your needs. This solution considers only `http[s]?://`-protocol and `www.`-servers...

**EDIT:**
If you want count and domains:

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://zelleke.com | \
  sed -n '4,$ s@^.*http[s]?://\([^/]*\).*$@\1@p' | \
   sort | \
     uniq -c | \
       sed 's/www.//'
```

gives

```
2 wordpress.org
10 zelleke.com
```

**Original Answer:**

You might want to use `lynx` for extracting links from URL

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://zelleke.com
```

gives

```
# blank line at the top of the output
References

   1. http://www.zelleke.com/feed/
   2. http://www.zelleke.com/comments/feed/
   3. http://www.zelleke.com/
   4. http://www.zelleke.com/#content
   5. http://www.zelleke.com/#secondary
   6. http://www.zelleke.com/
   7. http://www.zelleke.com/wp-login.php
   8. http://www.zelleke.com/feed/
   9. http://www.zelleke.com/comments/feed/
  10. http://wordpress.org/
  11. http://www.zelleke.com/
  12. http://wordpress.org/
```

Based on this output you achieve desired result with:

```
lynx -dump -listonly http://zelleke.com | \
  sed -n '4,$ s@^.*http://\([^/]*\).*$@\1@p' | \
   sort -u | \
     sed 's/www.//'
```

gives

```
wordpress.org
zelleke.com
```

Comment: yes this also gives me a result close to what i want.. Thank you.

Comment: @theodros-zelleke `sed` doesn't support the non-greedy operator `?`. Do `http[s]*://` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can remove path from url with sed:

```
sed s@http://@@; s@/.*@@
```

I want to say you also, that these two lines are wrong:

```
found=$(cat $file | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d '"' -f2 | sort | uniq | awk   '/http/' > $links)
output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)
```

You must make either redirection ( `> out` ), or command substitution `$()`, but not two thing at the same time. Because the variables will be empty in this case.

This part

```
content=$(wget "$url" -q -O -)
echo $content > $file
```

would be also better to write this way:

```
wget "$url" -q -O - > $file
```

Comment: Yes i have removed the `output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)`

Comment: But its still not totalling the domains that belong to the same top level domain and domain name. I removed `output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)` and replaced it with @JonLin's solution. Currently its returning the domains but not totalling them as to which ones belong to the same top level domain

Answer (score 0):

you may be interested by it:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B

explain the way to parse uri using regex.

so you can parse an uri from the **left** this way, and extract the "authority" that contains domain and subdomain names.

```bash
sed -r 's_^([^:/?#]+:)?(//([^/?#]*))?.*_\3_g';
grep -Eo '[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$' # pipe with first line, give what you need
```

this is interesting to:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/78502575/124/Extracting-the-Host-from-a-URL

assuming that url always begin this way

```
https?://(www\.)?
```

is really hazardous.